# Firebase storage security rules not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I try to imply security rules on Firebase storage using metadata and it not working:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match <firebase-storage-url> {
  match /{userId}/{allPaths=**}{
  allow read: if resource.metadata.userid== userId;
  allow write: if resource.metadata.userid== userId
  }
  }
}


StorageMetadata  metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setCustomMetadata("userid", user.ID)
            .build();

filepath = mStorage.child( user.ID + "/" + String.valueOf(chatmessageamount + 1) + ".mp3");
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to use metadata for security rules and that how I implemented that and it not working

Comment: the first part is the storage security rules. and the second part is how I upload file to firebase storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {  // this should be this string literally, no need to put in the bucket name
    match /{userId}/{allPaths=**}{
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow write: if request.resource.metadata.userId == userId;  // request.resource is the resource being written, resource is what already exists (which on first write will be null)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I try and not working. The read is always working regardless restriction

Comment: I didn't use the line: match /b/{bucket}/o{ maybe this is the reason that the read always working. What the importance to use the bucket line instead of my project name?

Comment: Rules match the RESTful path to the object (which is `/b/some-bucket/o/path/to/object`), the `{bucket}` captures whatever bucket name. Without that, the rules should have failed, since they should match nothing. Note that if you're downloading via download tokens, the rules are ignored.

Comment: @MosheGil Consider accepting this answer (click on the checkmark to the left of it) if it answers your question so that others know it has been solved.